# No matching int(str) overload found error in squish

Tags: python, casting, squish

I'm getting an error when I want to convert a string to an `int` in Python.
I am using `Squish` with Python. I don't see what the problem is because the `int()` function works fine when I tried in python online console. It's possible to be a Squish problem?

The error:

```
No matching 'int(str)' overload found: Following overloads are available:  int::int()  int::int(int)  int::int(int *)
```

Comment: Definitely a Squish problem, since Python doesn't even *have* overloading.

Comment: Definitely, this looks like a C++ error - the underlying library is receiving a string where it expects an integer. We can't say more without seeing the code.

Answer (score 3):

Squish replaces several Python symbols/names, including *int*. To access Python's *int* do so via Python's *__builtin__* module:

```
import __builtin__

# string representation of an int
a = '3'

# use built-in function to convert to int
b = __builtin__.int(a)
```

Also see [Squish's int vs. Python's int](https://doc.qt.io/squish/python-notes.html#squish-s-int-vs-python-s-int), and for more general information about Python in Squish see [Python Notes](https://doc.qt.io/squish/python-notes.html).

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem and obviously it's a Squish problem according to kb.froglogic.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=131084. Squish defines its own int() function and that's why I was getting the error